# Is there a away to make a chromeless Terminal on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app, window, styles

Is removing or modifying the chrome-bar (topbar) of an OS X window possible? The window in question is the window from Terminal.app.

Comment: In Mac OS, we call that the "title bar". By the way, how are you planning to move the window without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible if you're developing your own application. If you're using someone else's then it's only possible if they wanted to make it possible.

Comment: Can I just wrap the terminal in my own app?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a chromeless Terminal window you may be interested in a program such as [TotalTerminal](https://totalterminal.binaryage.com) (formerly known as [Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/)) - an application that allows you to show and hide a Terminal window whenever you want.

The other alternative is to modify Terminal.app but I would caution against it as the downsides outweigh any advantage but quite a fair margin.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/), if you haven't already.  It's an open source OS X terminal app.  I've looked into the source and it's pretty approachable if you've had a little Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty):

> “Alacritty is a modern terminal emulator that comes with sensible defaults, but allows for extensive configuration. By integrating with other applications, rather than reimplementing their functionality, it manages to provide a flexible set of features with high performance. The supported platforms currently consist of BSD, Linux, macOS and Windows.”

```
# ~/.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml
window:
  dimensions:
    columns: 0
    lines: 0
  padding:
    x: 0
    y: 0
  dynamic_padding: true
  decorations: none
  startup_mode: Windowed
  opacity: 1.00
```